# Programmatic Instantiation of a Widget with mixins

Tags: javascript, dojo

We have started creating a bunch of mixins that extend the functionality of dijits and our own widgets (_WidgetBase based).   Using 1.8 declarative, we use data-dojo-mixins and the parser does what we want with them.

However, in a couple places, we're instantiating widgets programmatically.  Is there a way to tell Dojo to instantiate this class with this/these other class(es) mixed in?   Or do we have to use safeMixin separately?

Any advice would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like createSubClass did what I wanted.  Making a new class out of my original class with my mixin.  You can see the output in the console [at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwadkins/Jnr2x/4/)

```
require([
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dojo/_base/window',
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
        'dojo/_base/lang'
    ],
    function(
        dojoDeclare,
        win,
        _WidgetBase,
        templatedMixin,
        lang
    ) {
    console.clear()
    var R = dojoDeclare([_WidgetBase, templatedMixin], {
        templateString : "<div>Go go widget gadget</div>",
        postCreate : function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            console.log("r - postCreate");
        },
        startup : function() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            console.log("r - startup");
        }
    });

    var M = dojoDeclare([], {
        postCreate : function() {
            console.log("m - postCreate");
            this.inherited(arguments);
            console.log("m - postCreate after inherited");
        }
    })

    var X = R.createSubclass(M);
    var r = new X();

    console.log([X, R]);

    r.placeAt(win.body());

    r.startup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've always created my custom widgets that extend `_WidgetBase`:

```
define([
    'dijit/_WidgetBase',
    'path/to/module1',
    'path/to/module2' /* etc. */
], function(WidgetBase, module1, module2) {

    /* Here you can define your module's functions */

    var myVar = 42;
    var foo = function(num){
        alert("My var is " + myVar);
    };

    return declare([WidgetBase], {

        /* This is the widget you are creating. Public variables should go here */

        myGlobalVar = "I did stuff",
        doStuff: function(a, b) {
            module1.doSomething(a);
            module2.doSomethingElse(b);
            alert(this.myGlobalVar);
        },
        callDoStuff: function() {
            alert("I'm gonna doStuff");
            this.doStuff(3, 5);
        }
    });

});
```

Of course, if you just want to extend a widget programmatically, you can always fall back to using `dojo._base.lang::extend()` (to literally extend a widget), or `dojo._base.lang::mixin()` (to modify the widget's prototype).

From the [DojoToolkit website](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/lang.html#extend-vs-mixin):

```
require(["dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/json"], function(lang, json){
  // define a class
  var myClass = function(){
    this.defaultProp = "default value";
  };
  myClass.prototype = {};
  console.log("the class (unmodified):", json.stringify(myClass.prototype));

  // extend the class
  lang.extend(myClass, {"extendedProp": "extendedValue"});
  console.log("the class (modified with lang.extend):", json.stringify(myClass.prototype));

  var t = new myClass();
  // add new properties to the instance of our class
  lang.mixin(t, {"myProp": "myValue"});
  console.log("the instance (modified with lang.mixin):", json.stringify(t));
});
```

Comment: this isn't about creating a custom widget, but about mixing in functionality to an existing widget while preserving widget base's lifecycle methods, similar to how the parser does it with data-dojo-props.  I could probably get the same thing done with delcaring a private class that inherits from the widget and mixes in my extension, but that seems like more code than I need, given that the parser gives this for cheaper.

Comment: @Ray Wadkins, the second part of his answer covers that. use `dojo/_base/lang::extend()` to mixin all existing widgets of type A with a specified mixin or use `dojo/_base/lang::mixin()` to mixin a single widget of type A with a specified mixin.

Comment: And if the mixin contains a postCreate method (with this.inherited(arguments)), it will get called during the widget lifecycle same as mixins used with declare?

Comment: Yes. Just think of it as smashing two objects together; the right gets smashed into the left. If I have `foo = {a:"old", b:"useless"}` and `bar = {a:"new", c:"shiny"}`, running `lang.mixin(foo, bar)` yields `foo = {a:"new", b:"useless", c:"shiny"}`. This is cool, but nothing fancy is being done besides enhancing the left object. I'm not sure if that answers your question, but as long as your widget structure is well-formed (proper extends and mixins), `postCreate()` should still work the same, provided you still extend `_WidgetBase`.

Comment: Hmmm...I tried it in a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rwadkins/Jnr2x/) and extend didn't work, the "Target's" lifecycle methods never fire.

However, I switched to safeMixin and tried it and got better results (http://jsfiddle.net/rwadkins/Jnr2x/1/).   The inheritance didn't really work the way I hoped it would, but all of the lifecycle methods got executed, which is all I really need.  It did matter that the mixin was saveMixin's target.  Switching R and M around prevented R's startup from executing at all, while the inheritance worked the way I expected.